# Error en Join con JPA y SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

estoy haciendo un proyecto con JPA y Spring Boot en el cual necesito hacer una consulta entre dos tablas: "Cliente y Factura" tengo mi entidad Cliente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    private Integer idCliente;
    private String nombre;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    private Factura factura;

    public Integer getIdCliente() {
        return idCliente;
    }

    public void setIdCliente(Integer idCliente) {
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;

    public Factura getFactura() {
        return factura;
    }

    public void setFactura(Factura factura) {
        this.factura = factura;
    }
    // Método toString();
}
```

Y mi entidad Factura que he hecho de esta manera:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FACTURA")
public class Factura {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_cliente")
    private Integer idCliente;
    private int region;
    private double iva;
    private double comision;

    public Integer getIdCliente() {
        return idCliente;
    }

    public void setIdCliente(Integer idCliente) {
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }

    public int getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(int region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public double getIva() {
        return iva;
    }

    public void setIva(double iva) {
        this.iva = iva;
    }

    public double getComision() {
        return comision;
    }

    public void setComision(double comision) {
        this.comision = comision;
    }
    // Método toString();
}
```

Mi clase ClienteRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {
    List<Cliente> findById(int idCliente);
}
```

Y mi clase ClienteController: (Estoy dividiéndolo en MVC, espero sea correcto)

```
public void consultaJoin(String idCliente) {
        List<Cliente> lista = clienteRepository.findById(idCliente);
        for(Cliente cte : lista) {
            System.out.println(cte.getNombre() + " " + cte.getFactura().getIva());
        }
}
```

Y mi clase main a la cual le paso por argumento el id_cliente:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    @Autowired
    ClienteController clienteController;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        clienteController.consultaJoin(3);
    }
}

Al ejecutarlo me manda este error:
 o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 3
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: More than one row with the given 
identifier was found: 3
```

Llevo ya algunos días con esto, he investigado sobre el error pero aún no doy con la solución. Alguien podría orientarme en ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? ¡Gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo , te aconsejo que tu tabla de Cliente tenga una relación @OneToMany (uno a muchos) con Factura , así un cliente pueda tener varias facturas , pues llevándolo a la vida real así tendría que ser .

entonces en tu clase de cliente modificarias esta linea

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente")
    private Factura factura;
```

por esta linea

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "cliente" ,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Factura> facturas ;
```

Acá lo que haces es establecer la relación uno a muchos , luego mapearla con la tabla cliente , le das un fetch de tipo perezoso para que no traiga inmediatamente todos los datos.

Y en tu clase de Factura quedaría así

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Cliente cliente ;
```

y para terminar te recomiendo que las facturas tengan su propio id entonces y que este tambien sea auto incrementable .

Y con respecto al error debes fijarte en tu metodo del controlador que estas pidiendo como parametro un String , cuando los campos idCliente son de tipo Integer.

Espero haberte ayudado , yo estoy haciendo un programa similar puedes hecharle un vistazo y quizas puedas guiarte de mejor manera .

https://github.com/danielmanriquez/app-facturas

Comment: Hola @Daniel he hecho lo que comentas pero esto modifica los datos que necesito en el controller ya no puedo llamar al campo "iva" además de que me sale el error: Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Lo del argumento lo tengo parseado, siento no haberlo puesto, Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @Lorena en tu repository tienes que borrar la linea ` List<Cliente> findById(int idCliente);` y dejar esa interface vacia , ya que JpaRepository ya te da todas las herramientas que necesitas por si sola , y en tu metodo consultaJoin tienes que cambiar `List<Cliente> lista = clienteRepository.findById(idCliente);` por `Cliente cliente = this.clienteRepository.findById(idCliente)` y luego no hay necesidad de iterar con un forEach , solo tienes que imprimir los datos del cliente . Si fuera el caso que quisieras imprimir una lista tienes que acudir al metodo findAll() .

Comment: Si es una consulta entre dos tablas ¿Cómo recupera los datos de factura? porque así como me lo comentas sólo se trae los del cliente, pero necesito algunos de cliente y algunos de factura. ¡Saludos!

Comment: un metodo que devuelva la factura del cliente seria algo asi `public List<Factura> obtenerFacturasCliente(Integer idCliente){ Cliente cliente = this.clienteRepo.findById(idCliente); return cliente.getFacturas(); }`  Gracias a que asignamos un fetchType= lazy jpa hara la consulta automaticamente para traer la factura . El codigo que escribi tienes que acomodarlo en tu codigo .